# Error installing a package on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, dpkg

I am trying to setup Apache Confluent Platform and maven on my instance Ubuntu 16.04
I am getting the following error after I performed the 2 steps

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install confluent-platform-2.11


Hit:1 ://packages.confluent.io/deb/2.0 stable InRelease Hit:2 ://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease      Get:3 ://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                           Hit:4 ://packages.confluent.io/deb/3.3 stable InRelease                  Get:5 ://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                         Hit:6 ://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease      Hit:7 ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease      Hit:8 ://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease Fetched 204 kB in 0s (470 kB/s)                Reading package lists... Done W: ://packages.confluent.io/deb/2.0/dists/stable/InRelease: Signature by key 1A77041E0314E6C5A486524E670540C841 468433 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1) Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies:  confluent-platform-2.11 : Depends: confluent-kafka-2.11 (>= 0.11.0.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: confluent-kafka-connect-replicator (>= 3.3.0-1) but it is not going to be insta lled
                           Depends: confluent-support-metrics (>= 3.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: confluent-control-center (>= 3.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed  confluent-platform-oss-2.11 : Depends: confluent-kafka-2.11 (>=
0.11.0.0-1) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

sudo apt-get -f install

Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
   confluent-kafka-2.11
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   confluent-kafka-2.11
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/44.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 49.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 99862 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../confluent-kafka-2.11_0.11.0.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking confluent-kafka-2.11 (0.11.0.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-2.11_0.11.0.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):  
**trying to overwrite** '/usr/share/java/kafka/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar', which is also in package confluent-ka fka-2.11.7 0.9.0.1-1 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing:  
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-2.11_0.11.0.0-1_all.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The error is mentioning around overwriting the file. I referred to multiple help links and so deleted osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar as well but it still shows the same error.

Its now happening while installing any Ubuntu package

**Let me know if anyone knows around the issue**

Comment: Try removing first, if it already exists but improperly setup.
sudo apt-get remove confluent-platform-2.11

Comment: This link can be of some help, it helped me previously.
[Fix broken packages Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it)